# how to send data from java to php then to mysql data base

Tags: java, php, mysql

I am tryning to send data from java to php then from php to mysql data base so this my php code :

```
         <!DOCTYPE html >
         <html >
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Document sans titre</title>
        </head>

          <body>
       <?php
            require_once('conn.php');
            mysql_select_db($db)or die('ERREUR'.mysql_error());
            extract($_POST);


          $req="insert into `fdt_tab`               values(null,'".$date."','".$kpi_category."','".$kpi_indicator."','".$kpi_image."')";
          mysql_query($req)or die (mysql_error()."\n".$req);
          mysql_close();
          echo " Insertion faite avec succés !! " ;?>
          </body>
         </html>
```

and this is my java code :
                              try {

```
                        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/fdt/inser.php");

                        PhpPostConnect con = new PhpPostConnect(url);

                        System.out.println("la connexion est faite avec succés!!");
                        try
                        {


                            con.send("5"+"02/02/2015"+"categorie"+ "cssr"+"CSSR_PS.png");

                            String meldung = con.read();
                             System.out.println(meldung);      
                                    if(meldung.contains("OKAY"))
                            {
                               System.out.println(meldung);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882135/how-to-send-data-from-java-applet-to-php-to-mysql-and-read-data-from-mysql-to-ph) to write this code 
the problem that when I want to insert data in my data base I found that an empty ligne has been added to my data base !!

Comment: Why are you doing this through PHP instead of writing directly from Java to the database?

Comment: it is the instructions of my professor :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending POST data, the expected format of the information is:

```
name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3...
```

Where `name1`,`name2`,`name3` are the names of your parameters, and `value1`, `value2` and `value3` are the values of those parameters. The names and the values are expected to be [url-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). So, for example, a parameter "storeName" with a value like `H&M` is supposed to be sent over as `storeName=H%26M`.

The problem is that you didn't do that. You just concatenated the values of all your parameters and sent them like this:

```
con.send("5"+"02/02/2015"+"categorie"+ "cssr"+"CSSR_PS.png");
```

This sends `502/02/2015categoriecssrCSSR_PS.png` to the server. The PHP script sees that, and it can't break it into parameters properly, and so you end up with all the parameters being undefined. In PHP, this means that when you use them in the `$req` SQL string, they are all empty.

You need to add the names of the parameters as you expect them in the PHP (`date`,`kpi_category` etc.), and format the whole data I mentioned above, with the values URL-encoded (for example, you can't send `02/02/2015` as a value. `/` is a reserved character and has to be percent-encoded).

---

Additional advice: Your PHP script is really very unsafe. Do not, ever, use `extract`. It's very unsafe. Anybody can set any variable in your program by sending you that variable as parameter. It may be annoying to type, but always use the variables as `$_POST['var_name']` (or `$_REQUEST['var_name']` etc.) and put only those that you need in variables if you want by using `=`, not by `extract`.

Also, check that each variable that you need has been passed: is set, is not empty, and contains a reasonable value.

All strings that you get from the parameters, and are supposed to be used by the database, are supposed to be escaped, since you don't know if somebody will try to hack your program and send you strings that contain a single quote. This will break your SQL. Use `mysql_escape_string( $_POST['var_name'])` to escape the string in MySQL.

Comment: @jiji Then please consider marking the answer as "Accepted".